# How to properly float div and numbered list in css?

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

When floating a div the numbering of lists around it doesn't fit. The numbers are in the div rather than besides it. How does one properly do this? [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/eLLa8274/)

```css
div {
  float: left; 
  width: 10em; 
  height: 10em; 
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<ol>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ol>
```

**Edit**

The result I have in mind is that the numbered list keeps it default format but floats around the list just as in any normal writer application.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`list-style-position: inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) on `ol`

```css
div {
  float: left; 
  width: 10em; 
  height: 10em; 
  background-color: lightblue;
}

ol {
 list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
Test
<ol>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This seems to work. But changes the original style of the list in that there will be more indentation when the list is not next to the div: https://jsfiddle.net/eLLa8274/3/

Comment: No. Well, it changes the whole way the list looks. Compare: https://jsfiddle.net/e77nLLbz/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/e77nLLbz/2/. What I had in mind was a list that looks just as the default one but floats properly.

Comment: I understand but i don't think there is easy solution for that, how about something like this https://jsfiddle.net/eLLa8274/5/?

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks the floating of the list around the div. I have tried to make myself more clear in an Edit to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Another option to consider is this:

```
ol {overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Great. So far this seems to me the best answer since it leaves the way the lists are formatted when not next to a float. https://jsfiddle.net/pnwgLjan/6/

Comment: My bad. Unfortunately, I did a copy-paste error. I did not mean to have many, but only one ordered list. Then the formatting does not stay in tact: https://jsfiddle.net/eLLa8274/2/. The ordered list does not float around the div. I have also changed the fiddle in my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it with margin/padding property for ul, or just add css:

```
li{list-style:num inside;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pnwgLjan/4/

Comment: Unfortunately, this changes the whole way the list looks. I wanted to keep the list look as it was. See the edit I made to the question.

Comment: However, I am quite interested in how one would do this using the margin/padding property.

Answer (score 0):

you need but the list in other div with float like this

`<div style=float:left;></div><div style=float:left;><ol></ol></div`

https://jsfiddle.net/w9bhd3jn/

Comment: This makes the numbered list not float around the div anymore. I have tried to make myself more clear about what I had in mind in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is simply to add right margin to the div:

```
margin-right: 30px;
```

```css
div {
  float: left; 
  width: 10em; 
  height: 10em; 
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
Test
<ol>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ol>
Test
```

Comment: Thanks. But I guess you can see from the normal text above and below the list that it leads to different formatting. Maybe to have a natural floating with lists is not possible after all. Surprising.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do it is by using css counter to increment each li item and output it the number as a :before. You can then use padding, margin (whichever is preferred).

With this approach you can also then style list item numbers however you like. Rather than stick to the default styling.

Here is how to use CSS increment. Works like a charm :)

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-increment/